# '.heif' file is not downloading, server is returning 404 Not Found error

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, iis, windows-server-2016

The anchor link for downloading .heif extension is not working. I'm getting `404 Not Found` error but the file is present on the server. The same link is working for every known type of files like 'png, jpeg, pdf, docx etc'. I'm using following anchor tag for downloading of file:

```
    <a ng-href="{{clientProfile.stdidentityDocObj.payeE_DOCUMENT_FILE}}"
                               target="_blank" download>Download
    </a>
```

The error I'm getting is:
[image: 404 Not Found error]

The website is deployed on Windows Server 2016. What could be the issue here? Is there any way that I can be able to download these type of files also?

Comment: You need to tell IIS about the extension: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: Thanks, added the mime type (image/heif) for it in IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell IIS about the file extension, see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) for more information, but it states:

> IIS 7 will not return file types that are not added to the `<staticContent>` element or that have mappings in the `<handlers>` element by default. This behavior prevents unauthorized access to files that do not have mappings in the IIS 7 configuration settings.

So to fix this, add a `staticContent` element:

```xml
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <!-- Add this line... -->
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".heif" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've added the mime type in IIS directly. Does it make any change if I add in IIS directly instead of configuration file?

Comment: Doing it in IIS manager will add this entry to your `web.config` file, it's the same action.